# Not Understanding how these arrays are adding a value to one based on the array inside it

Tags: java, arrays

I've decided to take a journey into the powerful yet daunting world of Java I'm coming from C++ however I've just started, I'm picking up quickly to catch up to where I am in C++, however I stumble across something I simply can't seem to understand and wrap my head around it. Could someone please help me understand this logic and how it works? Thank you for your time and sorry for my ignorance?

Basically, the program its suppose to keep a tally of the values and capture the one that is out of bounds of the responses array. Now I still quite understand it.

```
package stuPoll;


public class studentPoll {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        int[] responses = {1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 3, 5, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 14};

        int[] frequency = new int[9];

        for (int anwser = 0; anwser < responses.length; anwser++){

            try {
                ++frequency[responses[anwser]];
                System.out.println(responses[anwser]);
            }
            catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                System.out.println(e);
                System.out.printf("responses[%d] = %d\n\n", anwser, responses[anwser]);
            }
            }

        for (int rating = 1; rating < frequency.length; rating++){
            System.out.printf("responses[%d] = %d\n\n", rating, frequency[rating]);

        }
        }

}
```

I'm currently learning about exception handling, however, I came across this part of the code

```
++frequency[responses[anwser]];
System.out.println(responses[anwser]);
```

I can see that its incrementing frequency[] array however when you run the code it seems to counts how many of that specific value there is on the responses array and count it to frequency however it knows the exact subscript to count it on and I can't understand how or why it does that? I'm very sorry for wasting your time but could someone help a newbie programmer understand this? I'm a bit of a visual learner so I've trying to draw it but I still don't understand?

Comment: The code snipped works because it is exactly the same as if it was written as `frequency[responses[answer]] = frequency[responses[answer]] + 1`

Answer (score 0):

ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Catches wrong index accesses of your array.
Ex: Say if your array is of size 3, and you access arr[3] then you get an exception because you accessed an unavailable index:

```
int arr[] = {1,2,3};
arr[0] //ok
arr[1] //ok
arr[2] //ok
arr[3] //exception as size is 3 and it does not exist
```

The code snippet counts the frequency of ratings in your array.
(i.e how many responses have rating 1, how many have rating 2 and so on)

the frequency is stored in the freq array where freq[0] corresponds to number of responses with rating of 0, freq[1] corresponds to number of responses with rating of 1 and so on.
so

```
++frequency[responses[anwser]]; //increases the count with rating responses[answer](i.e an item in the response array)
```

Now in your case when you reach 14, you get an indexOutOfBound exception as you are only checking for responses from 0-9

Hope it helps

Comment: So does the responses array, in this case, act like a for loop? For example when the code starts it starts on frequency[0] and the responses[] then iterates until it finds a 0 and then it increments, if not it moves to frequency[1] 2 3 and so on until the array meets a value that frequency doesn't cover the bounds of and it catches the error?

Comment: you use for loop to loop through the responses array. for each response(A.K.A rating)(i.e reponses [i] ) you increment the corresponding index of freq array (i.e count of the rating )

Comment: Thank you very much @Aditya